# flash live media encoder Linux

Tags: media

Apparently there is no way of installing Adobe media encoder for Linux unless you use "Wine" which I'm not about to do because seems very messy option.

Does anyone know of any other open source live media encoders that will install on Linux and play H.264 codec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine has improved a lot over the years and is considered a good framework by many. You can try [this](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) for your codec solution on linux though.

Comment: Ah yes VLC, I had installed it but didn't manage to get it working. Thanks maybe I'll give it another go.